# Convert Visual Studio project from x86 to x64

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio 2019 project that I want to convert from x86 to x64. I went into "Configuration Manager" and selected "Active Solution platform" but only Win32 is listed.  So I selected "new" and under "Type or selected the new platform" only ARM was listed.  So I typed in x64.  But my project still as WIN32 references throughout.  I feel like there would have been a WIN64 or x64 option under the "Type or selected the new platform".  What am I doing wrong?  Do I really have to go throughout my project properties to change any win32 reference?

Comment: Go to Add/Remove programs, Modify your Visual Studio install, and make sure all the x64 packages are installed.  For native C++ I see the x64 setting under Linker > All Options > Target Machine